# how create a segue from view controller to itself

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

My app have categories and this categories can have infinite subcategories or videos. My principal View controller have a uicollection vith cells. I need that that when i select a category, if the category have subcatehories then create other view controller like this the first with subcategories, but if the category have videos go to other different view controller.

i think that i need two segues from my cells in my principal view controller:

- one of them wit destination to show videos view controller
- other go to it self for show all the subcategories.

I want to drag a segue from my cell of my voew controller, to itself. So I can push "infinite" instances of that particular view controller(for all possible subcategories).

But i dont know how drag a segue from view controller to itself. when i try to drag a second segue xcode deleted my first segue.

thanks you friends.

Comment: You should create the view controller in code and show/push it in your code as well instead of creating the segue.

Comment: i dont need a segue?when a instead, in my prepareforsegue function?

Comment: Didnt you ask the same yesterday ? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31640508/how-to-create-a-segue-from-view-controller-to-itself

Comment: Please do not ask twice. We all had some questions that hasn't an answer. Respect to others, you are not the only one asking.

Answer (score 7):

just create custom segue from the code. You aren't then limited to only one segue like when using storyboards.

```
 UIViewController *toViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OtherViewControllerId"];
 MyCustomSegue *segue = [[MyCustomSegue alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"" source:self destination:toViewController];
 [self prepareForSegue:segue sender:sender];
 [segue perform];
```

or create a view controller with ID and push it

```
UIViewController *myController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController: myController animated:YES];
```

Comment: How to do this in Swift?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer in Swift based on @MaciekWrocław

```
let destinationViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DestinationViewController")

let segue = UIStoryboardSegue(identifier: "SegueToProfileViewController",
                                      source: self,
                                      destination: anotherProfileVC,
                                      performHandler: {
                                                self.navigationController?.show(anotherProfileVC, sender: self)
        })

        self.prepare(for: segue, sender: user)
sege.perform()
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4:

First, add this class extension on UIViewController somewhere in your codebase:

```
extension UIViewController {
    class func storyboardInstance(storyboardId: String, restorationId: String) -> UIViewController {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardId, bundle: nil)
        return storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: restorationId)
    }
}
```

Then instantiate an instance of YourViewController class (using the extension above), and push to it from your navigationController:

```
let destinationVC = YourViewController.storyboardInstance(storyboardId: "YourStoryboardName", restorationId: "idYouSetInStoryboard") as! YourViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationVC, animated: true)
```

Comment: Don't forget to **Embed In** to **Navigation Controller**

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the segue and add the code to create VC and push it when cell is tapped in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!){

    // Create your view controller and push it
    // pass data if needed
    self.navigationController.pushViewController(yourViewController, animated: YES);
}
```